# Does geth have internal RPC help, similar to `bitcoin-cli help`?

Tags: go-ethereum, cli

Does geth have "internal" RPC help, equivalent to bitcoin-cli help?

You can call bitcoin CLI either with `bitcoin-cli help`, which lists all the RPC calls, or with `bitcoin-cli help getmempoolentry` (for example).

Does geth have something similar? I cannot find it if it has.

Answer (score 1):

check out this wiki page

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC

you can use tab to get the available functions  in a specific namespace: exp admin.+tab gives you

[image]

but you need to refer to the documentation to get the explanation of each function.

Comment: I don't want help to geth itself. I want the list of RPC calls and some description.

Comment: for RPC calls check https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC

Answer (score 1):

No, ethereum does not have internal RPC documentation, the only documents are on github wiki

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC